# Creating a content type in the CCK with several categories and multiple options

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I have to create a content type with multiple options divided into categories.

For example, imagine that you want to create a content type about cars and each car has multiple categories (engine, dimensions, serial items ...), and for each category, you have multiple options. For example for dimensions: weight, large, height, volumen ...

It would represent something like this:

Category 1

- Option1
- Option2
- ...

Category 2

- Option1
- Option2
- ...

...

There would be in total about 8 categories and 10 options for each category, so about 80 options in total.

All the options would be booleans (either it has the option, or it hasn't).

The options that must be supported are defined and not variable, meaning, I know which options will be required before hand.

My question is how would be the best way to manage this in Drupal.

My first reaction would be to use fields of integer type and with a widget type Single on/off checkbox.

The problem I see with this is that it would create a field into the content_type table for each one of the options, meaning there would be about 50 fields in that table.

Another option it occurs to me would be to create a text field for each category, and that the content creator inserts the options available for that category in that specific item, separated by commas.

Which would be the best approach about this?